# Allow Woocommerce shop manager to assign a role when creating a user

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dropdown, roles

The custom role *shop manager* created by Woocommerce can only assign the *customer* role when adding a user.

I'm trying to let *shop manager* choose from the different roles by enabling the capability *promote_users*.

```
function shop_manager_add_users() {
    $role = get_role( 'shop_manager' );
    $role->add_cap( 'promote_users' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'shop_manager_add_users');
```

It's not working, the selection drop down only offers the *customer* role, and other roles are still hidden.

Is there another capability that should be enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Woocommerce adds specific restrictions to the Shop Manager role.

This worked and allowed a *consigner* custom role to be available in the dropdown :

```
function shop_manager_role_edit_cap( $roles ) {
    $roles[] = 'consigner';
    return $roles;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_manager_editable_roles', 'shop_manager_role_edit_cap' );
```

Source: [developer.woocommerce.com/](https://developer.woocommerce.com/2018/10/11/woocommerce-3-4-6-security-fix-release-notes/)